# WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content, see http://g.co/ng/security#xss

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I have getting warning like this in my angular sample.

**WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content, see http://g.co/ng/security#xss**

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e4otvr-mjm48m?file=app.component.ts

Some one please help me out of here.

Thanks in advance.

I have tried this solution.

https://blog.angularindepth.com/warning-sanitizing-html-stripped-some-content-and-how-to-deal-with-it-properly-10ff77012d5a

Still warning occurs.

```
getCellContent(e): string {


    if (e && e.targetCell.className.indexOf('e-valuescontent') > -1 ) {
        template = '<input type="checkbox">'; //Here,  you can append the html elements

    }
     else {
        template = '';
     }

    return this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, template) || '';
}
```

WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content, see http://g.co/ng/security#xss

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(template);
```

instead of

```
return this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, template) || '';
```

Angular needs to trust the html you inserting through innerHTML. This `bypassSecurityTrustHtml(template)` method will help. It worked for me. Let me know yours.